# Uneven spaces between lines in TextView with HTML text

Tags: android, html, textview

I am using Html to form the appearance of text inside TextView. This is the easiest approach I found possible without using multiple TextViews. Yet, for some reason the gaps between lines are different. And I am struggling to find out why. I am attaching screenshot for better idea what is going on.

At the left side >>  `setText(message);` to see the Html I am using.

At the right side >> `setText(Html.fromHtml(message));`

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you show us some CSS?

What kind of HTML is this?

Comment: There is no CSS. It is only Html tags I am using in Android TextView component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt, there will be any use of my answer for anyone. But the problem was with html only.

There was a space between `</small> </font>` so the space was made in normal font instead of small one. And because larger symbol (space) was in in the line. The spacing between the lines got distorted.